# Optimizing Gremlin Query for Neptune outV() inV()

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

I'm new to gremlin and I'm trying to optimize the query.
Any ideas what can be done?

```
traversal = graph.V(fromID).toE(toID)

traversal.project(1KEY, 2KEY)
.by(valueMap().with(WithOptions.tokens))
.by(outV().valueMap().with(WithOptions.tokens))
.by(inV().valueMap().with(WithOptions.tokens));
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you're attempting to do with this query? Are you trying to fetch an edge, all of the edge's properties, and then all related information for the "from" and "to" vertex of that edge?

Comment: Adding to the question above, when you say optimize, is it performing poorly? How many nodes is it having to return? `valueMap` is going to return every property for each node found. Neptune has a profile API that will give you a bit more insight into where time is being spent and how much data is being touched.